# how to get JSONArray from sharedpreferences into Adapter

Tags: android, json, android-sharedpreferences

In the first activity to load in my app I put my `JSONArray` into `Sharedpreferences` (as a `String`):

```
    //put myJsonArray into shared preferences file as a String
    //Convert back to Json later, in the adapter
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("MyData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    //we want to edit SharedPreferences
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
    //put the string value into SharedPreferences, with the key "key_value"
    editor.putString("key_value", myJsonArray.toString());
    //commit the string
    editor.commit();
```

I can get this `string` in another `Activity` and convert it back to a `JSONArray` easily with:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("MyData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String json_array = sharedPrefs.getString("key_value", "0");
        try
        {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json_array);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("MYAPP", "unexpected JSON exception", e);
        }
```

But when I put the above code in the `onBindViewHolder` of my `adapter`, or anywhere else in my `adapter`, I am getting: `NullPointerException` and my app crashes.

Please tell me how I can solve this.

Where it crashes it says:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException at com.example.chris.tutorialspoint.SharedReviews.SharedPopulistoReviewsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(SharedPopulistoReviewsAdapter.java:130)
```

My `onBindViewHolder` code is:

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {


        SharedReview r = the_Shared_reviews.get(position);

        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("MyData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String json_array = sharedPrefs.getString("key_value", "0");
        try
        {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json_array);
            System.out.println("SharedAdapter, the jsonarray is :" + jsonArray);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("MYAPP", "unexpected JSON exception", e);
        }

        ((ReviewHolder) viewHolder).category.setText("Category: " + r.getCategory());
        ((ReviewHolder) viewHolder).name.setText("Name: " + r.getName());
        ((ReviewHolder) viewHolder).phone.setText("Phone: " + r.getPhone());
        ((ReviewHolder) viewHolder).comment.setText("Your Comment: " + r.getComment());

        //set an onClick listener for the row, if it's clicked anywhere
        ((ReviewHolder) viewHolder).itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            //When the review is clicked in PopulistoListView
            //then show that review
            public void onClick(View v) {

                SharedReview sharedReview = (SharedReview) SharedPopulistoReviewsAdapter.getItem(position);

                //we want to pass the review_id of the sharedReview being clicked
                //to the ViewContact activity, and from there post it and get more
                //info for that sharedReview - address, comments etc
                Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), ViewContact.class);
                //pass the review_id to ViewContact class
                i.putExtra("review_id", sharedReview.getReviewid());
                v.getContext().startActivity(i);
            }

        });
    }
```

`Line 130` is:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("MyData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: Suggest showing the code that crashes, not the code that's working. Include the stack trace and info so we can map the crash line number with your code snippets.

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman Edited my question.

Comment: did you make sure that context is no null?

Comment: I added now `if (context != null) { code in here}` and app doesn't crash any more, but it skips over the `sharedpreferences` part.

Comment: You can acquire the context from the viewHolder's view. Don't retain the context but instead use `((ReviewHolder) viewHolder).category.getContext()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because you have not initialized `context`. Either you must initialize `context` by passing context as a parameter when creating the object of the adapter or you can get the context from a view.
To get the context from a view change the line to:

`SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = ((ReviewHolder) viewHolder).category.getContext().getSharedPreferences("MyData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

Comment: This is the correct method to acquire a context. Do this.

Comment: thanks, working on it now, don't fully understand what's going on but no errors any more, although my `system.out.print` is giving no result, must need to initialize `context`, will mark as correct answer when solved.

Comment: Try using `android.util.Log` class static methods instead of `System.out.print`.